# django-cms div tags with cmsplugin class interfering with slider

Tags: javascript, css, django-cms

I am using Django CMS 3.0.3. I've written a cms plugin with 2 CMSPluginBase derived classes, one adds a slider to a placeholder and another one is for adding slides as children to the slider.

In live mode everything works fine, but when I am editing content, I can't use the slider. The reason is that django-cms is decorating the html code with additional elements like this:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="cms_plugin cms_plugin-2" style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; display: block;">
        <!-- Slider Item -->
        <div class="slider-item"> [MY SLIDER CONTENT] </div>
        <!-- /Slider Item --> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I got the HTML/CSS/JS from somebody else and I would preferable not use another slider. What options do I have to work around this problem?

Is there a way in django-cms to switch off the wrapping of plugins in "content mode" only, but to have the placeholder `<div>` included in "structure mode"? That would not be super convenient, but a workaround that I can live with.

Is there something else, I could do? I don't want to touch the slider itself. It might get an update and then I'd have to adjust it to adjust the slider to my needs again.

Answer (score 1):

django-cms is need to wrap your plugin with `<div class="cms_plugin cms_plugin-2">` for relation with "structure mode". There are no other variants.